# How to get object that not match in another object lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have 2 arrays with objects.

```
const a = [
 {
  name: 'John'
 },
 {
  name: 'Adam'
 }
]

const b = [
 {
  name: 'Adam'
 }
]
```

I want to get the object is not the same in the array and also get the object that is same in arrays as well.

```
const same = [
 {
  name: 'Adam'
 }
]

const not_same = [
 {
  name: 'John'
 }
]
```

Using lodash library is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: try something on your own, and then come back with the question. HINT: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`intersectionBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy) and [`xorBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#xorBy) as follows:

```js
const a = [{
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Adam'
  }
];

const b = [{
  name: 'Adam'
}];

console.log(_.intersectionBy(a, b, 'name')); // values present in both arrays
console.log(_.xorBy(a, b, 'name')); // values present in only one of the arrays
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.partition()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partition) to get two arrays according to a certain criteria:

```js
const a = [{
    name: 'John'
  },
  {
    name: 'Adam'
  }
];

const b = [{
  name: 'Adam'
}];

const bMap = _.keyBy(b, 'name'); // create a map of names in b
const [same, not_same] = _.partition(a, ({ name }) => name in bMap); // partition according to bMap and destructure into 2 arrays

console.log('same: ', same);

console.log('not_same: ', not_same);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```